# Why mapping not working when data streaming?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I need to map lat, long to geo-point. I stream data every 10 seconds from a website. I get only first occurrence of the position from json. I did mapping. and when I run my code the data is streaming but can't see the mapped in Kibana.

Here is my code.
    es = Elasticsearch('http://ip:port',timeout=600)

```
settings = { "settings": {
                     "number_of_shards":1

                     },
          "mappings" : {
                    "properties":{
                         "geo": {
                            "properties": {
                                "location":{
                                   "type": "geo_point"

                                    }
                                  }
                        }
        } } }

es.indices.create(index = "myindex", ignore = 400, body=settings)
def data_collect():
 data = requests.get(url = URL).json() 
 del data["positions"][1]
 positions = data['positions']

 if "satlatitude" in positions and "satlongitude" in positions:
  data['positions']['geo'] = { 'location':      
                           str(positions['satlatitude'])+","+str(positions['satlongitude'])}

  es.index(index='myindex',doc_type='mydoc',body=data)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do( data_collect)
while True:
 schedule.run_pending()
 time.sleep(1)
```

Results of GET satellitepositions/_mapping as bellow:

```
 {
 "satellitepositions": {
 "mappings": {
  "satelitepos": {
    "properties": {
      "info": {
        "properties": {
          "satid": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "satname": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "transactionscount": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "positions": {
        "properties": {
          "azimuth": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "dec": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "eclipsed": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "elevation": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "ra": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "sataltitude": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "satlatitude": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "satlongitude": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Results of GET satellitepositions as bellow:

```
 {
 "satellitepositions": {
 "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {
  "satelitepos": {
    "properties": {
      "info": {
        "properties": {
          "satid": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "satname": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "transactionscount": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      },
      "positions": {
        "properties": {
          "azimuth": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "dec": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "eclipsed": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "elevation": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "ra": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "sataltitude": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "satlatitude": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "satlongitude": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "long"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"settings": {
  "index": {
    "creation_date": "1590738791943",
    "number_of_shards": "5",
    "number_of_replicas": "1",
    "uuid": "HLstIPiXQcyJC5_laowxNQ",
    "version": {
      "created": "6040399"
    },
    "provided_name": "satellitepositions"
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

Comment: I think you have to create a template event, with the type for each field, in kibana.

Comment: @Val, I made the changes to data['geo'], but in Kibana I don't see 'location'

Comment: Can you show the mapping of your index using `GET myindex/_mapping`?

Comment: When myindex/_mapping, I don't see location

Comment: @Val, and I'm using ES version 6.4.3

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why there's is no `geo` object field in your mapping... Are you sure you're checking the right index?

Comment: yes I gave just a name for tmy index for the sake of this question as "myindex", but it's real name is "satellitepositions" in my real code.

Comment: just an idea, since my ES version is 6.4.3 , is it correct to keep doc_type in index?

Comment: @Val, is this code is working with your ES and Kibana?

Comment: Can you copy/paste the whole content you get from `GET satellitepositions` into your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214892/discussion-between-user-and-val).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding that logic in the Python script, let's use an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) that does the job for you.

First, run the following call in Kibana to create the `geo-pipeline` ingest pipeline that will create the geo point out of the lat/lon fields you get from the satellite API.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/geo-pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": """
          ctx.positions = ctx.positions[0];
          ctx.geo = [
            'lat': ctx.positions.satlatitude,
            'lon': ctx.positions.satlongitude
          ]
          """
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Next, you can simplify your Python code like shown below. You'll note that I've modified the index settings to make sure all documents that are indexed in your index run through the `geo-pipeline` first, and get the `geo` field created properly.

```
es = Elasticsearch('http://ip:port',timeout=600)

# create index
settings = {
  "settings": {
    "index.number_of_shards": 1,
    "index.default_pipeline": "geo-pipeline"
  },
  "mappings": {
    "satelitepos": {
      "properties": {
        "geo": {
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
es.indices.create(index = "satellitepositions", ignore = 400, body=settings)

# routine for collecting data
def data_collect():
  data = requests.get(url = URL).json() 
  del data["positions"][1]
  es.index(index='satellitepositions', doc_type='satelitepos', body=data)

schedule.every(10).seconds.do(data_collect)

# kick it all off
while True:
 schedule.run_pending()
 time.sleep(1)
```

This should work as you expect and your documents will get a `geo` field of type `geo_point` that you can show on a map.

Comment: Thanks for asking,but sorry, not working , I don't know why